# C - Print int variable in float

Tags: c, floating-point, int

after looking for all answers I still coudnt find solution for my code.

Variables needs to be type INT, but in one case I need to print decimal solution. I have tried with casting, still didint work.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int sum = 6;
  int product = 24;
  int differenz, result, division, rest, decimal;

  differenz = ++product - sum++;
  result = differenz * sum;
  division = result / 9;
  rest = result % 9;
  decimal = result / 9.0; 

  printf("Result = %d\n", result);
  printf("Integer division = %d\n", division);
  printf("Remainder = %d\n", rest);
  printf("Division = %.2f\n", (float) decimal);


  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Result = 133

Integer division = 14

Remainder = 7

Division = 14.00 <-- Here I am supposed to print 14.76
```

I have also tried:

```
float b = (float) decimal;
printf("Division = %.2f\n", b);
```

Still Division = 14.00

Any tip will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Variables needs to be type INT". Well, then you're hosed. An int just can't store a float value.

Comment: Here `division = result / 9;` it's an integer division and hence the result is also an integer. `Variables needs to be type INT, but in one case I need to print decimal solution` -- it's impossible to do that with int variables. If `int` is capable representing float, we wouldn't need floats at all.

Comment: If your task is to show a decimal value by using only integers you'll need to introduce scaling.

Comment: An **integer** variable stores **integer** values, not float values. The problem is so obvious and can be seen using single-stepping in a debugger and watching the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you created the variable decimal as an int and you're trying to print it as a float.

Either create the variable as a float, or print it as an int, but you cannot mix both.

Also, casting an int to a float will just add the ".00", you won't be able to modify that.

Comment: That answers my question. I will go then with the float. We will see whats going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "decimal" cannot represent the result of the division correctly if it is declared as an integer. You need to declare it as a floating point number like this:

```
int main()
{
  ...
  int differenz, result, division, rest;
  float decimal;
  ...
  printf("Division = %.2f\n", decimal);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought casting would help. Because, in the task it is asked to use INT variables. Looks like i have to go with the float.